# How to show Abstract title

Tags: languages, abstract, classicthesis

I think that is something very simple, but I can't see the Abstract title in the `abstract` environment.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel} 

%Loaded here: microtype,graphicx,booktabs,caption,tabularx,hyperref,amsmath
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Is it also possible to have a double abstract (one in English and one in Italian) in the same page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. To set a title use the option `abstract=on`.
2. To change the language load both languages via option and uses the command `\selectlanguage` provided by `babel`.
3. To set a double abstract put the environments `abstract` in a `minipage`

Here a small example:

```
\documentclass[abstract=on]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[italian,english]{babel} 

%Loaded here: microtype,graphicx,booktabs,caption,tabularx,hyperref,amsmath
\usepackage{classicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage{classicthesis}

\begin{document}
\clearpage
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{italian}
\begin{abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok for the title, but in this way I have two English abstracts. Is it possible to translate it?

Comment: @Baduel: I thought you know how to change the language. Sorry. I edited my post.