# Remove "Abstract" title from Abstract

Tags: titles, abstract

I am using the abstract package, but want to remove the title and associated horizontal spacing.  Is there an easy way to do this?

(Be aware: this may be a complete newby question, as I have only recently started to use LaTex.  Please be kind!)

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
\geometry{margin=1in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{abstract}

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
\pagestyle{fancy} % options: empty , plain , fancy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % customise the layout...
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}

%%% SECTION TITLE APPEARANCE
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\mdseries\upshape 
        \sectionrule{15pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt} }

\title{Title Title Title}
\author{Alistair Collins, Company}
\date{} % Activate to display a given date or no date (if empty), otherwise the current date is printed 

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
\maketitle

\begin{onecolabstract}
One Column Abstract - it is the Abstract title that I wish to remove.\\
\end{onecolabstract}
]

\section{Section Title}
\textit{Italic text as first paragraph\\\\
}
Main text

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}    % clear the title
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{empty} % originally center
```

The title is stored in `\abstractname`, so we clear it; but `abstract` puts the title between `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`, but actually `center` is stored in the macro `\absnamepos`; so we abuse LaTeX features and place the (empty) title in the (inexistent) `empty` environment so the result is that nothing will be printed and no excess space will be set.

Comment: with `\usepackage[english]{babel}` the abstract title does not disappear. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @JoãoBravo Do `\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}}` instead of just `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}`.

Comment: From the accepted answer on https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38334/how-to-show-abstract-title I would assume adding `abstract=off` to the options of `\documentclass` should work just fine. Can someone verify?

Comment: @EgorHans That. An work if the class supports such an option, which `article` doesn’t.

Answer (score 45):

```
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
```

Slightly more economical than the proposed solution (no need for `abstract` package).

Comment: Works, but needs to be set *after* \begin{document}