# Remove "abstract name" in abstract (cyr)

Tags: naming, abstract, cyrillic

In [Remove "Abstract" title from Abstract](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42482/15040) people were able to remove the abstract name from abstract. I downloaded an article template with colored fonts from HowToTeX.com, changed it a little to accept cyr symbols (russian) and now the abstract name doesn't go away!

```
%%%%% Preamble
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T2C]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}                           % Input encoding
\usepackage{amsmath}                                    % Math

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bl}{rgb}{0.0,0.2,0.6} 


\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec} 
\allsectionsfont{\color{bl}\scshape\selectfont}

%%%%% Definitions
% Define a new command that prints the title only
\makeatletter                           % Begin definition
\def\printtitle{%                       % Define command: \printtitle
    {\color{bl} \centering \huge \sc \textbf{\@title}\par}}     % Typesetting
\makeatother                            % End definition

\title{Гибридные вложенные сети Петри \\ 
        \large \vspace*{-10pt} Описание нового формализма\vspace*{10pt}}

% Define a new command that prints the author(s) only
\makeatletter                           % Begin definition
\def\printauthor{%                  % Define command: \printauthor
    {\centering \small \@author}}               % Typesetting
\makeatother                            % End definition

\author{%
    Калашников Антон Олегович \\
    akalashnikov@hse.ru \\
    \vspace{20pt}
    }

% Custom headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}                   % Enabling the custom headers/footers
\usepackage{lastpage}   
    % Header (empty)
    \lhead{}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{}
    % Footer (you may change this to your own needs)
    \lfoot{\footnotesize \texttt{HowToTeX.com} - Template}
    \cfoot{}
    \rfoot{\footnotesize page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}  % "Page 1 of 2"
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

% Change the abstract environment
\usepackage[runin]{abstract}            % runin option for a run-in title
\setlength\absleftindent{30pt}      % left margin
\setlength\absrightindent{30pt}     % right margin
\abslabeldelim{\quad}                       % 
\setlength{\abstitleskip}{-10pt}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\color{bl} \small \slshape}    % slanted text


%%% Start of the document
\begin{document}
%%% Top of the page: Author, Title and Abstact
\printtitle 

\printauthor

\begin{abstract}
Здесь будет короткое описание проделанной работы и выводы.
\end{abstract}

%%% Start of the 'real' content of the article, using a two column layout
\section{Heading on level 1 (section)}
Some text.
    \begin{split}
    (x+y)^3     &= (x+y)^2(x+y)\\
                    &=(x^2+2xy+y^2)(x+y)\\
                    &=(x^3+2x^2y+xy^2) + (x^2y+2xy^2+y^3)\\
                    &=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3
    \end{split}                 
\end{align}
Some text.

\subsection{Heading on level 2 (subsection)}
Some text. 
\begin{align}
    A = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    A_{11} & A_{21} \\
    A_{21} & A_{22}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\subsubsection{Heading on level 3 (subsubsection)}
Some text.

\paragraph{Heading on level 4 (paragraph)}
Some text.


\section{Lists}
\subsection{Example for list (itemize)}
\begin{itemize}
    \item First item in a list 
    \item Second item in a list 
    \item Third item in a list
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Example for list (3*itemize)}
\begin{itemize}
    \item First item in a list 
        \begin{itemize}
        \item First item in a list 
            \begin{itemize}
            \item First item in a list 
            \item Second item in a list 
            \end{itemize}
        \item Second item in a list 
        \end{itemize}
    \item Second item in a list 
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Example for list (enumerate)}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item in a list 
    \item Second item in a list 
    \item Third item in a list
\end{enumerate}

\subsubsection{Example for list (3*enumerate)}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item in a list 
        \begin{enumerate}
        \item First item in a list 
            \begin{enumerate}
            \item First item in a list 
            \item Second item in a list 
            \end{enumerate}
        \item Second item in a list 
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Second item in a list 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. It had smth to do with babel packge and russian language, so the appropriate command was    \addto{\captionsrussian}{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}} before the abstract initialization.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `\abstractname` "later" since it is actually set `\AtBeginDocument`. So, rather use

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{}}
```

which will reset it back to nothing. You may also want to use something different to `\quad` for the abstract label skip (since you're removing it anyway).

Comment: Better `\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand\abstractname{}}` for a `\selectlanguage{russian}` after `\begin{document}` would resurrect the name. Also `\captionsenglish` should be taken care of.

Comment: I didn't try the first solution, maybe i will, but the second worked like a charm. What should I do with the \captionsenglish?